# How to stop recursivity when I got the result of sudoku's grid?

Tags: c++, recursion, sudoku

I am trying to solve a grid of sudoku using a recursive function with backtracking. And actually, it works but the recursivity never stops, even with the return statement. And I don't know how to make it works.

```
bool solve(int idl, int idc){ 

  if( idl == N ){
    std::cout << std::endl;
    printGrid();
    return true;
  }

  if( grid[idl][idc] != 0 )
    if( idc == N-1 )
      tmp = solve(idl+1, 0);
    else
      tmp = solve(idl, idc+1);

  for(int i=1; i<=N; i++){
    if( ok(i, idl, idc) ){
      grid[idl][idc] = i;
      if( idc == N-1)
    tmp = solve(idl+1, 0);
      else
    tmp = solve(idl, idc+1);
    }else{
      grid[idl][idc] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have an `if tmp: return true` at the bottom of your for loop

Comment: Why don't you listen to your compiler warnings? Machines can help you, no need for human attention.

Comment: More information about your code is needed to review your control flow. Without the knowledge of how your `grid` is set up, what that `tmp` serves, what `ok` means, etc., I can't really tell whether you have a reasonable base case and recursive steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code, that give a ridiculously bad run-time and also produce wrong results.

1. When the current cell not empty (`grid[idl][idc] != 0`), than you call the function recursively, but afterwards you also try to fill the current cell with each number between 1 and 9. This is obviously really bad. You overwrite a number, that is fixed in the original sudoku grid. You should only do the `for(int i=1; i<=N; i++){...}` part, when `grid[idl][idc] == 0`. 

   This is the reason your program is slow. Even if there is already a number, it tries to fill it with all possibilities.
2. Setting the current cell back to `0` (`grid[idl][idc] = 0;`). You are performing this only if `ok` returns `false`. This is not enough. Imagine the following: `ok` returns `true`, so you write the digit into `grid[idl][idc]` and call `solve` recursively. Image that `solve` can't solve the grid using this digit, `solve` returns `false`. So we also have to erase this digit. You don't do this. 
   It's enough to erase the current cell after the for loop, just before you return.
3. If you found a solution, exit as quickly as possible. You can do this by checking the return value of the recursive calls. If `solve(...,...)` returns `true`, than you also can return `true` immediately. You don't need to check other possibilities for this cell. Your already finished.

Here's the corrected code. Notice, that I didn't compile it and didn't tested it. But I'm pretty sure it's correct. I added quite a few comments, so that you can understand the changes.

```
bool solve(int idl, int idc)
{ 
    if (idl == N)
    {
        //sudoku solved
        std::cout << std::endl;
        printGrid();
        return true; //
    }

    if (grid[idl][idc] != 0)
    {
        // current cell has already a number, 
        // move on to the next cell
        if (idc == N-1)
            return solve(idl+1, 0);
            // if solve(idl+1, 0) returns true, then the sudoku is solved, 
            // so we also return true. If solve(idle+1, 0) returns false, 
            // then the sudoku is not solved and we also return false. 
        else
            return solve(idl, idc+1);
            // ditto
    }
    else
    {
        // the current cell is empty
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            if (ok(i, idl, idc))
            {
                grid[idl][idc] = i;
                if (idc == N-1)
                    if (solve(idl+1, 0))
                        return true;
                        // since the sudoku is already solved, exit the program
                        // if solve(...) return false, the sudoku isn't solved, 
                        // so we have to search further and can't exit. 
                else
                    if (solve(idl, idc+1))
                        return true;
                        // ditto
        }

        // if the program came this far, that means that all attempts of 
        // filling the current cell with digits failed. 
        // So we empty the current cell, and backtrack. 
        grid[idl][idc] = 0;
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Btw, I'm not sure if this code is already fast enough to solve sudokus in a reasonable time. I've combined my backtracking sudoku solver with some logic strategies, like the "Hidden Singles" strategy.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, First of all, sorry for my english, it is not my main language.
Now lets talk about your problem, as I see, you use the return statement but never use the result of your function. You are doing `tmp = solve(idl+1, 0);` but never use the tmp again. so the result of your function is just lost and dont make stop the other ones. You should probably make something like this

```
 bool solve(int idl, int idc){ 
 bool result = false;
  if( idl == N ){
    std::cout << std::endl;
    printGrid();
    result = true;
  }
 // if the result is not true than continue to solve
 if(!result){
  if( grid[idl][idc] != 0 )
    if( idc == N-1 )
      result = solve(idl+1, 0);
    else
      result = solve(idl, idc+1);
}
// if the result is not true than continue to solve
     if(!result){
      for(int i=1; i<=N; i++){
        if( ok(i, idl, idc) ){
          grid[idl][idc] = i;
          if( idc == N-1)
        result = solve(idl+1, 0);
          else
        result = solve(idl, idc+1);
        }else{
          grid[idl][idc] = 0;
        }
      }
     }
     return result;
    }
```

Comment: There are still quite a few flaws in this code. For instance, `result` gets overwritten in each iteration of the for loop. So the resulting value is quite meaningless.